# Does a closed form solution for the value $a$ exist?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble trying to solve this algebraically for the value a, ie a = some function, where a, g and v are independent variables.  Is there a closed form solution for this?

$g$ = $ln(1+a)$ - $\frac{0.5v}{(1+a)^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a transcendental equation in $a$. Have a look at [Lambert W-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you make a change of variable such that, for example, $x=\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}$, the equation write  $$2g=-\log (x)-{v}{x}$$ which is probably the best candidate for a Lambert function based solution as already mentioned by Ryuky. The solution of this last equation is given by $$x=\frac{W\left(e^{-2 g} v\right)}{v}$$ where $W$ is the Lambert function. Then, from $x$, we have $a$ from the definition.